# How can I chop this expression?

Tags: output-formatting

After some long calculations, *Mathematica* gives me this output:

$-0.11728 \, G_1^{\phantom{1}2} - 0.0692416\, G_1\, G_2 - 0.000011728 G_2^{\phantom{2}2}$

where `G1` and `G2` are two coefficients whose value I don't know, but I know that it must be integers and in the range `(0; 10)` (extremes excluded).

The last term is much smaller than the other two: how can I get rid of it? `Chop` doesn't work here since it only deals with numerical expressions.

Comment: Try `Chop[expr, 1.*^-4]`.

Comment: Note that the last term can be the major term in the range given, e.g., if `G1 = 0.001, G2 = 9`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but I forgot to write that the coefficients must be integers.

Comment: No. As I have written,  extremes are excluded.

Comment: Oh gosh. Somehow I read it several times as "included." Not sure how that happened.  Sorry for that.  (You should use @Michael E2 to make sure I'm notified.)

Comment: why not just do `/. G2^2->0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply `Chop` to just the numerical expressions you can use a `Rule` with a `Condition` that the subject is a number:

```
delta = 0.01;
rule = x_ :> Chop[x, delta] /; NumericQ[x]

exp = -1.2 G1^2 - 0.02 G1 G2 - 0.000011 G2^2;

exp /. rule
```

> -1.2 G1^2 - 0.02 G1 G2

Answer (score 2):

`Chop` accepts a second argument and appears to work only on numerical parts of an expression:

```
expr = -0.11728 G1^2 - 0.0692416 G1 G2 - 0.000011728 G2^2;

Chop[expr, 10^-3]
```

> -0.11728 G1^2 - 0.0692416 G1 G2

Comment: +1. You could even quote the docs to support your edit: "`Chop[expr]` replaces approximate real numbers in `expr` that are close to zero by the exact integer `0`."